# getting some unwanted math result in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck in problem with JavaScript calculation. as below code shows;

```
$(function(){   
        console.log(17.8575 + 142.86); // actual 160.71750000000003 and expected 160.7175 
        console.log(47.62*3); // actual 142.85999999999999 and excepted 142.86
    });
```

and I dont want to use toFixed() function.
How to come over this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any good reason not to use `toFixed`?

Comment: That's how floating point math works. One possibility is to switch to integer math.

Comment: because I am working with money, where 47.62 is Rate and 3 is Qty and want to calculate exact amount as 142.86.

Comment: Is this answer what you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript